# Oracle .NET MySQL 8.0.21 Client throwing strange "same name are not supported" error

Tags: mysql, .net-core

When I upgraded from MySQL Client 8.0.20 to 8.0.21 in a .net-core 3.1 application, I get this strange error when trying to call a stored procedure in AWS Aurora.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): same name are not supported.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcData(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.AddNew(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcedure(MySqlConnection conn, String spName, String cacheKey)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
```

In 8.0.20 (and several previous versions), it worked without any complaint. I can find nothing on the InterTubes about this error.

Procedure (very simple search proc):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`cdapoe`@`%` PROCEDURE `find_oeauthorizationassigned`(
IN p_username VARCHAR(120),
IN p_active_utc DATETIME
)
    READS SQL DATA
select * from oeauthorization.oeauthorizationassigned
where username=p_username and (p_active_utc < expiration_utc or expiration_utc is null)
```

Comment: Did you find it went away if you downgraded?

Comment: Yes. If I switch back - works fine. Very strange - I guess I'll try and file a bug report with the MySQL guys.

Comment: Bug report filed with MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100846

Comment: After creating a pure test program - the problem only occurs with CommandType.StoredProcedure but not with CommandType.Text. Updating bug at MySQL.

Comment: There is another 8.0.21 bug with a similar problem. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=100683

Comment: MySQL has "verified" my bug report... No word on fix. ;)

Comment: Downgrading worked for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has released MySQL Client 8.0.22 which appears to have fixed the problem.
The release notes don't mention my bug report - but there is another similar sounding bug. So maybe it was fixed incidentally.

MySQL has closed my bug report and claims it was fixed in 8.0.22.
I'm currently on 8.0.23 and it seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading from MySQL Client 8.0.21 to 8.0.20 is a known-good workaround.

The bug has been reported to and acknowledged by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

This error will come when you have the same function name as the stored procedure. Renaming either stored procedure or function will solve the issue